# JasperReport hyperlink isn't working when exporting in .pptx

Tags: java, jasper-reports, powerpoint

I have a jrxml with a hyperlink that is supposed to link to another page inside the document. This is the part of the jrxml used for the hyperlink:

```
<textField hyperlinkType="LocalPage">
        <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="148" height="20" uuid="ac8324b0-8d24-4ae1-8add-1813c96188ee">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
            <font fontName="MyFont" size="12"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        <hyperlinkPageExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(($F{pag}+$P{pageSize})-1)]]></hyperlinkPageExpression>
</textField>
```

The link works fine when exported in pdf (using Java net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter), the text is clickable and links to the correct page, but the same jrxml is not working when exported in pptx (using Java net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRPptxExporter).

I've tried setting property net.sf.jasperreports.export.pptx.ignore.hyperlink as false in the jrxml but nothing changed. I've also tried to add the configuration when exporting, like this, but it's still not working:

```
JRPptxExporter exporter = new JRPptxExporter();
SimplePptxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimplePptxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setIgnoreHyperlink(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

The pptx file is generated and everything looks fine, but there are no clickable links.

Do you know if there is any way to make hyperlinks working in pptx export using Jasper Report?